# Automatically refresh file list in a UWP app when files moved/added/renamed

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm working on a simple music player app for UWP and I have a couple of questions.
First of all here's my code

```
 private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;    
            await RetrieveFilesInFolders(folder);
        }



  private async Task RetrieveFilesInFolders(StorageFolder parent)
        {
            foreach (var file in await parent.GetFilesAsync())
            {
                if (file.FileType == ".mp3")
                {
                    var songProperties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
                    var currentThumb = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.MusicView, 200, ThumbnailOptions.UseCurrentScale);

                    var albumCover = new BitmapImage();
                    albumCover.SetSource(currentThumb);

                    var song = new Song();
                    song.Title = songProperties.Title;
                    song.Artist = songProperties.Artist;
                    song.Album = songProperties.Album;
                    song.AlbumCover = albumCover;
                    song.SongFile = file;
                    song.FileName = file.Name;

                    SongUC songUc = new SongUC(song);
                    sp1.Children.Add(songUc);
                }
            }

            foreach (var folder in await parent.GetFoldersAsync())
            {
                await RetrieveFilesInFolders(folder);
            }
        }
```

User control ctor

```
public SongUC(Song song)
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            txtTitle.Text = song.Title;
            txtAlbum.Text = song.Album;
            txtArtist.Text = song.Artist;
            txtName.Text = song.FileName;
            imgAlbumArt.Source = song.AlbumCover;
        }
```

1. How can I refresh the returned files automatically whenever a new song is added or moved or renamed
2. Is firing the `RetrieveFilesInFolders` method in the PageLoaded event handler the best way to get all songs. Or will it slow down the app if there's a huge collection of music in the music folder
3. How can I use animations whenever the files are retrieved to make things look nicer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a FileSystemWatcher:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

It allows you to catch events when files are being moved, deleted and renamed.

Comment: using System.Security.Permissions; not found :(

Comment: @Ra'edAlaraj Goto `Solution Explorer` right click on references and add reference search `System.Security` in assemblies checkmark to the system.security then ok.

Comment: Good find. I Missed that.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/2c4bf55b-1f6d-43bd-9327-f298715e5d12/uwpis-there-a-filesystemwatcher-class-equivalent-for-uwp?forum=wpdevelop), take a look at [file queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.StorageFolder#Windows_Storage_StorageFolder_CreateFileQuery) and their [`ContentsChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Search.StorageFolderQueryResult#Windows_Storage_Search_StorageFolderQueryResult_ContentsChanged) event.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I had missed the three letters UWP.